# Can't parse di p tag in page

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

i can't parsing the tag p in this page: http://multiplayer.it/articoli/127739-thief-la-vendetta-di-garrett.html

the code i use is:

```
try {
    // String BLOG_URL_LINKS = links;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(links).get();
    Element info = doc.select("div.col-1-1 article p").first();
    System.out.println(info);
    // Log.d("Links", linkss.text());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // In caso di errore
    Log.e("ERROR", "Parsing error");
}
```

in this way i parse the tag p but of di `em` class that is the part : `Ci siamo tuffati nelle prime ore di gioco dell'attesissimo reboot di Thief` but i need not that tag `p` but which has the entire content of the page. Where i wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "not that tag `p` but which has the entire content of the page"? What result you are trying to get?

Comment: the part that i want is: `UN ANNO DOPO
Un anno dopo il prologo di Thief, il mondo di Garrett è completamente cambiato: il furto andato male dodici mesi prima è coinciso con la scomparsa di Erin, ladra rivale allevata sotto la sua ala protettrice ma dall'animo troppo impetuoso per rimanervi, e la Città è piagata, oltre che dal pugno di ferro del Barone.....` understand now? and setting it in a textview

Comment: You showed where result should start, but where should it end? There are many sections in this article. Do you want rest of them?

Comment: Yes! I removed the .first tag and now it works in the console but not in the textview..how can I add in a textview? I tried with setText but not works.